# Document flowchart in Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

I know how to draw a simple rectangle in Raphael and I understand the sense of all its parameters. For example, these parameters give a nice rectangle with width equal to 201 and height equal to 179

```
 M0,0 L0,179 L210,179 L210,0 L0,0Z
```

But I do not want a simple rectangle, I want a document flowchart which should look like this

[image]

I know from [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/raphaeljs/9781449365356/ch04.html), that in Raphael I can draw curved lines, for example with these parameters:

```
M150,150 A100,70 0 0,0 250,220
```

But unfortunatelly, the book does not explain the sense of these parameters. I know what M means, but I do not know what A means and all the following coordinates.

So, how can I fix my initial rectangle coordinates to get a document flowchart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing piece here is the [SVG Path Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData).

Your initial rectangle:

```
M0,0 L0,179 L210,179 L210,0 L0,0Z
```

...is read as "go to 0,0, then draw a line to 0,179, then draw a line to 210,179, then draw a line to 210,0, then draw a line to 0,0 and return to the start." (The last part, the `Z`, is a little superfluous, since we've already closed the path.)

You want to replace the second line – from 0,179 to 210,179 – with an arc. I'm not a designer but I'd spitball that maybe a [Quadratic Bezier Curve](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataQuadraticBezierCommands) would do the trick:

```
M0,0 L0,179 Q53,159 105,179 T210,179 L210,0 L0,0Z
```

That means, starting at the Q, "draw a quadratic Bezier curve from the start point [0,179] to 105,179 using 53,159 as the control point. Then draw another from 105,179 to 210,179 using a reflection of the last control point." I haven't tested this path, so you may need to tweak the control point to get the curve you want. (Increasing the y distance between the control point and 179 will make a more dramatic curve; decreasing it will make a more gentle curve.)

The [Raphael documentation](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Paper.path) explains more about using paths in Raphael.

Comment: Thank you, sir! It is really helpful!